# PORT 3306 Already In use when i rn nodemon in NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, mysql-workbench, digital-ocean

I have a nodejs app which was running just fine all this time until I opened MySQL Workbench and also included  `.env` file in my project. I was in the process of deploying the system to Digital Ocean managed database service when I opened MySQL Workbench to visualise the process and not use the mysql shell. Everything worked fine and I migrated my db on to the DO database cluster.

I also wanted to make my app more secure, so I bumped into the `.env` file method and tried my best to follow through and I came up with this:

Step 1:

```
npm i dotenv --save
```

Step 2: Added  `require('dotenv').config()` to my server.js file

Step 3: Update my DB connection file

```
    const mysql = require("mysql");
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.HOST,
  user: process.env.USERNAME,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  //rsport     : (process.env.PORT),
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  multipleStatements: true,
});

conn.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Oops!, Failed to connect to the database.");
  } else {
    console.log("Database connection succesfull!");
  }
});

module.exports = conn;
```

Step 4: I set my local .env file and remote .env file accordingly

Step 5: I run `nodemon` the it return the following error:

```
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option server.js:27:17
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3306
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
    at Function.listen (G:\Maxiko Payment System\Systems\Management Apps\Microservices\mx-core\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Maxiko Payment System\Systems\Management Apps\Microservices\mx-core\server.js:47:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3306
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What am I doing wrong? honestly I do not think .env has anything to do with this, but i definately know MySQL Workbench made its own connection. So am I to believe that only one application can connect to a database at one time? That doesnt sound right to me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your node js server on a different port or run this command in command prompt (as administrator)

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>
```

Replace  with your port number that is in use(in your case 3306)

Then it will show you the PID of your process
Something like this

```
TCP 0.0.0.0:3306 0.0.0.0:0 LISTEN 77777
```

77777 is the PID

then run this command

```
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```

Replace  with the PID you got in the last command

Answer (score 1):

Its look like some other process already running on your port 3306
You can check it by using below command

> lsof -i tcp:3306

It will list you process that is already on the port 3306

> COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
> node   12012 user   20u  IPv6  86535      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)

That shows a process with PID 12012 already using your port 3306
If this process is redundant you can kill it by following command:

> sudo kill -9 PID

Replace PID with your process id which in my case is 12012
otherwise you can use some other port to run your node server

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. There was indeed another process running and using the same port. In app server initialization script , I was setting the port like this:

```
app.use('port', process.env.PORT || 5000)
```

Where at the the fdatabase connection file, I set the ports also as

```
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  port     : (process.env.DB_PORT),
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  multipleStatements: true,
});
```

So, as you can see, there is supposed to be a port conflict since i only had on `PORT=3006` variable in the `.env` file.

**SOLUTION**

All I had to do was specify the database port as

```
DB_PORT = 3006
APP_PORT = 5000
```

in the environment variables.

Thank you and Goog luck.